# PDF Comparison in Selenium

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdfcompare

I am comparing two PDF documents and getting the output in a result file. If both the PDF alignment is same then the difference is shown correctly, but if the alignment is not same of the two PDf files then the content is overlapping.

Could any one advise on this, below is the code to compare the PDFD files. Thank You!

```
import de.redsix.pdfcompare.PdfComparator;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String file1 = "C://Users//TEST1.pdf";
    String file2 = "C://Users//TEST.pdf";
    String resultFile = "C://Users//Results//result";

    new PdfComparator( file1, file2 ).compare().writeTo( resultFile);


    boolean isEquals = new PdfComparator( file1, file2 ).compare().writeTo( resultFile);
    System.out.println("Are PDF Files Similar : " + isEquals);
    System.out.println("Process Completed");
}
```

}

Comment: "Could any one advise on this" - please describe what your problem is. Is there an error message, does the computer go dark, does nothing happen?

Comment: I am able to get the output file. My problem is, if both PDF file is not in the same alignment the content is overlapping in a result file due to which couldn't find the differences..

Comment: Oops, I read too fast. Sadly, it means the files are different.

Comment: Yes, Tilman Hausherr...